# Snowflake file format - ' ' is not recognized with Copy Into command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a txt file, see screenshot below for some of the data in the file.

I'm doing a COPY INTO a new table with no data in it but I'm seeing this error:

> Timestamp ' ' is not recognized File 'my_file' , line 2, character 381
> Row 1, column "CLICKS"["TS":7]

In the file format below I've added `skip_header = 1` because headers are in the file, and `field_delimiter = '"'` because it looks like each value is separated by `" "`

This is my file format:

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT IF NOT EXISTS my_file_format
field_delimiter = '"'
date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
error_on_column_count_mismatch = True
skip_header = 1
escape = NONE
NULL_IF=('NULL','',' ','NULL','NULL','//N', '\\N', '    ') ;
```

[image]

I've also created the table:

```
create table my_table(
PAGE_URL VARCHAR,
NORMALIZED_PAGE_URL VARCHAR,
TARGET_URL VARCHAR,
NORMALIZED_TARGET_URL VARCHAR,
CLICK_ID VARCHAR,
IMPRESSION_ID VARCHAR,
TS TIMESTAMP,
PUBLISHER_DOMAIN_ID INT,
etc...
);
```

Comment: Your field delimiter is not it “, it is one or more spaces. As it appears that your file does not have a fixed delimiter string, it may not be processable

Comment: @NickW do you mean I’m unable to load the file to snowflake?

Comment: No - I mean that even if you correct the field delimiter you **may** find you have further issues you’ll need to address

Comment: @NickW I've tried doing this: field_delimiter = (' ','  ') but I'm unable to create multiple field_delimiters. What would be the best way to do this given my data?

Comment: Standardise the field delimiter in whatever process is generating this file?

Comment: I see, since this file is coming from an s3 bucket from an outside company I would just have to ask them what field delimiter they use?

Comment: Can you try using tab delimiter ...just a thought.

Comment: @Anand it did not work

Comment: @KristiLuna yes, get the file provider to document the file structure, field/row separators, etc

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that originates in whatever system the text file was created. It's not a problem that can be solved easily in Snowflake.